# Broken graphics tablet support on Windows 10 (No WinTab in the OS?)

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-services, graphics-tablet

I'm using an UGEE 2150 screen pen tablet on Windows 10 Pro (Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299), and seems that it's support has been broken again - last time this happened with the "Fall Creators Update", but has been fixed by the device manufacturer introducing new drivers. However, today my tablet has stopped working completely. Last windows updates have the date of 28th March, but I recall using the tablet after that date.

At first, I attempted to reinstall Ugee drivers, those gave me the standard prompt to uninstall tablet drivers first, but afterwards, I can't install the drivers since the installation app reports the tablet not being connected, despite that being not the case. Multiple attempts at disconnecting/reconnecting/restarts/switching to different ports proved no results.

Windows troubleshooting report a problem with "USB Device" and offer no help.

I have also noticed that in the control panel, I'm missing the "tablet pc" and other tablet related options that used to be there previously.

Not sure if I can check if this is related to any of the Windows updates, since Windows won't let me uninstall the most recent updates, or roll back to a previous version. The only option I have right now is "system restoration" options, which I don't want to do until I absolutely positively have to do it.

I tried to google potential solutions, seems most likely that the problem is related to WinTab in some way. I can't find any of the tablet related executables in the task manager and in the Services dialog, I can find the WinTab service but I'm unable to start it.

Error displayed when attempting to start WinTab service:

[image: Error displayed when attempting to start WinTab service]

The path reported to this service is C:\WINDOWS\System32\Drivers\WTSRV.EXE
This file is not present in my system folder and I found no means how to reinstall this service or download this file from an official source.

UPDATE: After going through the extracted drivers for my Tablet, I found a WTSRV.EXE but placing it in System32 does not fix anything - I still can't run the WinTab service from the Services panel.

UPDATE 2: I've plugged in another tablet (Wacom Intuos 3) - I was able to install drivers for it and seems that device is recognised in Windows, however, I can't run the Wacom Tablet settings app (Tablet not connected error) and the tablet works only in mouse mode (Which is a Windows default/fallback)

UPDATE 3: I've noticed that upon plugging the UGEE graphics tablet, it's reported as "Unknown Usb Device (device descriptor request failed)"